# No logon servers available to process your request

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-10

**Edit:** I've added new info in bold

I've got a Windows 10 Pro machine fully updated (Anniversary edition + 1607 update) joined to a Windows AD Domain (on Windows Server 2012).

This is a new install and it works fine **for most users**.

Today it refuses to allow **specific** domain users to logon, with the message `There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request`.

1. It is receiving an address via DHCP correctly from onsite DC.
2. Via DHCP it receives 3 DNS servers (which are also Domain Controllers, two offsite - available via VPN - and one onsite).
3. Logging into the affected computer as Admin, I am able to ping all three DCs via their IPs and via their FQDNs.
4. I have tried unjoining the PC from the Domain and rejoining it, and the problem persists.
5. **I have tried unjoining the PC from the Domain, completely deleting the computer account from AD, and rejoinig the PC to the domain.**
6. **I have tried completely reinstalling the computer from scratch.**
7. I have about 20 other computers at this site that aren't experiencing any problems **with the same users in question**.
8. They are all connected to the same main Switch (a managed, gigabit Cisco switch).

**In summary, I have a specific computer that fails to login specific users, but most users can actually login fine.  Meanwhile, those same users can login to any other machine without problems.**

Ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Check the services.msc and see if the workstation service is running. Personally beyond that (and maybe disabling IPv6) I'd likely just reimage the box.

Comment: Which DNS server is the Primary DNS for this client?

Comment: I gave up and am currently installing a fresh copy of Windows; hopefully the problem disappears.  The Primary DNS server is the onsite DC (and DHCP server).

Comment: OK, the problem still presents even after a fresh install.  However, there are new clues.  I've updated the original post with edits.

Comment: Well, here's were I ended up.  The users that had been logging in successfully so far were all Domain Admins or tech users (with local Admin privileges).  I tried logging in with a different standard Domain user, and it logged in fine with no problems.  After logging in with that user... the other Domain users with which I had had problems logging in suddenly started working.  I'm not really sure what the root cause was.

Comment: I did find a useful youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEd9SDe5x8Y where this guy explains how to troubleshoot the problem using the command line and PowerShell.  I hate how slow and long-winded this guy is, but he did have several seemingly very useful tips (none of which I had the opportunity to try myself, but maybe it will help someone else who arrives here via google).